# php merge arrays based on a value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to  send out emails to users from an array loop. Each email can be present in multiple array elements but, other than email, the rest of the elements are different.

I have this code below which tries to create populate two new arrays--one with just email while the other with other values, such as 'name' etc. What I finally need is an array which has something like:

```
$array_final(
             [0]email=>'whatever@com'=> (name1, name 2),
             [1]email=>"second@.com"=>name3,name4
            );
```

**here are my arrays and the loop:**

```
$array_emailedinfo_email = array();//will hold just email
$array_emailedinfo = array();//will hold email and other date; 

foreach($array_expiredmeetingscos as $mail) {

 if(isset($checkAgainst[$mail[1]])) {

    $array_emailedinfo_email[] = array(
                                             "email" => $checkAgainst[$mail[1]]
                                              );
    $array_emailedinfo[] = array( 
                                        "email" => $checkAgainst[$mail[1]], 
                                        "name" => $mail[2]
                                        );
        }
     }
```

I think I may be able to get the final array in the `foreach` loop itself but haven't figured that out. I have tried `array_merge()` etc but no luck, btw.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try to explain your `$array_final` in a better way, because it's not clear what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: $array_final will have the email address represented only once as per array element while the same array element can have multiple 'names'. The idea is that I can loop through the $array_final and grab the email and then grab the various names and send out in an email.

Comment: And what's the difference between `$array_final` and `$array_emailedinfo`? Could you edit your question and paste there e.g. output of `print_r($array_final)` you are expecting?

Comment: $array_final doesn't exist yet in my code. The output for $array_emailedinfo_email is: [0]=> array(1) { ["email"]=> string(18) "blah@blahblah.com" } while that of $array_emailedinfo is 0]=> array(4) { ["email"]=> string(18) "blah@blahblah.com" ["name"]=> string(32) " My name" . So the emails match in the two arrays.

Comment: Not pointing toward you, @Peter, but I didn't think this was going to be so difficult. I have two arrays with equal number of items with 'email' being common between the arrays. So simply a loop through the array with only emails to find matching emails in the other array so that other values could be grabbed from the other array.

Comment: It probably isn't difficult, but I really can't get what you exactly mean with `[0]email=>'whatever@com'=> (name1, name 2)` which isn't valid PHP syntax:)

Comment: Peter, thanks for the try. No, that was not supposed to be some syntax--but something like needed. I have one array with emails only; the other has matching emails and other data. I simply wanted to send ***one*** email to users per email address from the first array if emails matched in the second array which had the same number of elements and many matching emails. The Answer you have given me would cause multiple emails. So, I basically, needed a new array to hold just email and then matching data.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have two arrays:

```
$emails = array(array('email' => 'foo@example.com'), array('email' => 'bar@example.com');
$emails_info = array(array('email' => 'foo@example.com', 'name' => 'Alice'), array('email' => 'bar@example.com', 'name' => 'Bob'));
```

Now you would like to loop over `$emails` and find appropriate values in `$emails_info`:

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
  $info = array_filter($emails_info, function($item) use ($email) {
    return $item['email'] == $email['email'];
  });

  // because $emails_info[index]['email'] might not be unique, $info is array of such items
  print_r($info);
}
```

But I think it would be much easier to index one or both arrays with given email, e.g.

```
//variable from your question
$array_emailedinfo['foo@example.com'] = array(array('email' => 'foo@example.com', 'name' => 'Alice'));
```

**EDIT**

Function which finds appropriate item in array:

```
function find_in_emails($emails_info, $email) {
    foreach ($emails_info as $email_info) {
        if ($email_info['email'] == $email)
            return $email_info;
    }
    //not found...
    return array();
}
//usage
//...loop...
$info = find_in_emails($emails_info, $email['email']);
//...endloop...
```

Comment: Not working. Using your code (I even changed arrays to $emails and $emails_info) but the print_r gives a bunch of array() and then the actual data with multiple duplicate emails. Do I need to put your code in a function?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested my code, I've edited my answer already, note `return $item['email'] == $email['email'];` in the anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried the modified code--no more of those 'Array()' things but still a lot of duplicate emails. I know I am in a forloop and so that is causing the duplicates

Comment: You can use 'array_unique()' on those arrays with duplicate emails.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I can use your code though. It would be nice if this was a function which would return one email and all corresponding other data from the other array as they matched the email. I guess I will have to do something else. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks and I tried that too--same results: bunch of duplicates. Not exactly what I needed.

Comment: Update: The duplicate emails in my output for 'emails' array was coming from because the 'emails' array did have some duplicate values, which I have now removed. Now, I get unique values of emails along with corresponding other values--but only one row of corresponding values from the emails_info array. Not exactly what I needed but I think that's still improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it. Note in the new code, $emails is the same as $$array_emailedinfo_email and $emails_info is the same as $array_emailedinfo in the original Question, respectively.

```
$array_all_expired_info = array();
$i=0;
$temparray = array();
foreach ($emails as $email) {
if (is_array($email)) {
    $array_all_expired_info[$i] = $email;
    foreach($emails_info as $all_info) {
        if (in_array($email["email"],$all_info)) {
            $array_all_expired_info[$i][] = $all_info;
        }
}
}
$i++;
```

}//for

The final array is close to what I needed: First element is just the email the rest are arrays inside the respective elements. So now I can loop through all the elements, grab the emails, then grab corresponding data (which could be multiple, per email) and simply send email.

This all wasn't easy. But learned a few things about php arrays in the process. Well worth it.

Thanks.